# Aiogram: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, pyinstaller

Возникает ошибка при компиляции Python файла при помощи PyInstaller. В программе я использую aiogram, с ним и связана основная проблема. При запуске файла возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "system.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "aiogram\bot\base.py", line 83, in __init__
  File "ssl.py", line 765, in create_default_context
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Ошибка указывает на строку, где указан импорт самой библиотеки в виде:

```
from aiogram import *
```

По документации следует импортировать сторонние библиотеки (*ujson, cchardet, aiodns, aiohttp*). Но это не решает проблему. При сборке я использую такую команду:

```
pyinstaller -F --onefile --noconsole system.py
```

Кто знает, с чем связана такая ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Python не предназначен для сборки в exe файл, pyinstaller многие библиотеки просто не поддерживает.